# Why does a USB drive only mount as read-only after copying a disk image to it?

Tags: mount

I was preparing a USB thumb drive for installing Debian 8.3. Per the [installation instructions](https://www.debian.org/releases/jessie/amd64/ch04s03.html.en), it suggests:

```
cp debian.iso /dev/sdX     # e.g. /dev/sdb, no /dev/sdb1
sync
```

So I gave this a try. I noticed after doing this that if I try to mount `/dev/sdb1`, it does mount, however it always mounts as read-only, regardless of whatever options I pass. I tried with a few USB drives, with the same result.

Why will the drive only mount as read-only after doing the above? Is there a way to still mount it as rw?

Comment: It is the underlying file system, you are not supposed to write in the image DVD directly...see `mkisofs`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll likely notice that the filesystem as shown in `mount` is not EXT3 or FAT, it's [ISO 9660](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9660).  The process of making the filesystem for the disc is write-once, so when the disc image or disc is mastered, it can't be changed after that point.  The only thing you can do is copy the data to another filesystem type that is read-write (e.g. EXT3).  Given most people just use the ISO to install the OS and then ditch it after that, you might want to submit a separate question for why you want to modify the disc image.

Comment: I did not notice the filesystem difference. Is this technique `cp disc.iso /dev/sdb` the equivalent of running `dd if=disc.iso of=/dev/sdb`?

Comment: What do you mean by "mastered"? I noticed after doing this, if I try to check the usb drive with gparted or something, it shows no partitions. Various other program report errors about a corrupted GPT, etc. I don't really understand the state of the drive after running the `cp` command in my question.

Comment: They're equivalent in this case.  You're still taking the ISO filesystem and putting it on the USB drive without modifying it.

Comment: `/dev/sdb` refers to the entire disk rather than `/dev/sdb1` which refers to the first partition.  ISO discs generally don't have partitions on them, so when you take a copy of an ISO image and put it on USB, there's no partitions to show.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I always erroneously thought of ISO 9660 as a type of *partition* used on CDs and such rather than a file system.